# App Icon of iPhone only app missing on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, icons, appicon

I recently updated my iPhone only app and now I've got some users complaining that the Icon is gone on iPad.

So I looked into it and added ALL icons to the asset catalogue. Still, when I run my app on iPad, there is no icon. Even deleting it and fresh installing via Xcode is not working?!? I tried with iPad and iPhone icon sizes as well as with only iPhone icon sizes... Also restarting my iPad didn't help. Neither did a clean build...
Am I missing something? Did something change here lately? The last update to my app when it still worked was before iOS11...

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please share screenshot of your app icon assets catalogue?

Comment: I filled out all the images... nothing fanzy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that there was a Info-Plist Key for the iPad Icon... Don't really know how that one got there... But that was my problem...